# how to get multiple columns from yfinance api

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, finance, yahoo-finance

I am trying to query the yahoo finance api via the yfinance libarary, and have a list of 4000 tickers.

I can query the data that I need individually via:

```
yf.Ticker('msft').info['sector']
```

and

```
yf.Ticker('msft').info['symbol']
```

But I need to get the symbol and sector in one dataframe.

This is easy enough to do with merging, but there's no shared columns to merge on.

Furthermore, I have 4000 tickers I need to do this for, so I tried.

```
ticker_test = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN']
data_test = []
for ticker in ticker_test:
    try: 
        data_test.append(yf.Ticker(ticker).info['sector'] # also tried to do: ...info['sector','symbol'] but that did not work.
    except: 
        print("An Error has occured")
    
data_test_df = pd.concat(data_test, axis = 0)
```

Which yielded
`TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

But the problem is that it's not even grabbing the information from the yfinance api.

The ideal outcome is a dataframe which resembles:

```
    symbol    sector
0   MSFT      technology
1   AAPL      technology
2   AMZN      consumer cyclical
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the result from the API and directly select only one item (`sector` in your case). However, the result of the API is a dict with a lot of items. My solution would be to save the result of the API in a variable and then select both of the items you want for each ticker. From the list of these you can then create a dataframe.

Following is the code:

```
ticker_test = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN']
data_test = []

for ticker in ticker_test:
    result = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
    row_items = [result['symbol'], result['sector']]
    data_test.append(row_items) 

data_test_df = pd.DataFrame(data_test, columns=['symbol', 'sector'])
```

Output:

```
    symbol  sector
0   MSFT    Technology
1   AAPL    Technology
2   AMZN    Consumer Cyclical
```